# Obtaining left and right side words of entities with SpaCy

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I have been working on NLP project with SpaCy to obtain left and right side words of all entities and dump them to JSON format.

Here is the function that I tried:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.new_side_words_json = dict()

def side_words(self, text):
    words = nlp(text).ents[0]
    side_words_json = [{'LeftSideWord': str(words[entity.start - 1]),
                        'Entity': str(entity),
                        'RightSideWord': str(words[entity.end])}
                       if not words[entity.start - 1].is_punct 
                       and not words[entity.start - 1].is_space 
                       and not words[entity.end].is_punct
                       and not words[entity.end].is_space
                       else
                       {'LeftSideWord': str(words[entity.start - 2]),
                        'Entity': str(entity),
                        'RightSideWord': str(words[entity.end + 1])}
                       for entity in nlp(text).ents]
    self.new_side_words_json['SideWords'] = side_words_json
```

In some cases, this algorithm works. However, it is a quite ugly solution in my opinion as it does not control the conditions enough. This algorithm is highly dependent on text format. I would like to build something solid that works with every document.

What I mean by that is, in the text file, there can be many punctuations or spaces one to another. I am just controlling two levels below or above.

What I would like to do is, create an algorithm that finds the meaningful words that are previous and next to the entity but not punctuation or space or maybe not even stop-words.

How can I tweak this algorithm to get the previous and next meaningful word of all entities?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at the end. It is still pretty ugly. However, it works as I want.

I post the code here so anyone who crosses with the same type of problem it might give an idea of the solution.

```
    for entity in doc.ents:
        self.entity_list = [entity]
    right = [
        {'Right': str(words[entity.end])} if (entity.end < self.entity_list[-1].end) and not words[entity.end].is_punct and not words[entity.end].is_space
        else
        {'Right': str(words[entity.end + 1])} if (entity.end + 1 < self.entity_list[-1].end) and not words[entity.end + 1].is_punct and not words[entity.end + 1].is_space
        else
        {'Right': str(words[entity.end + 2])} if (entity.end + 2 < self.entity_list[-1].end) and not words[entity.end + 2].is_punct and not words[entity.end + 2].is_space
        else
        {'Right': 'null'}
        for entity in nlp(text).ents]
    result = [{**dict_left, **dict_entities, **dict_right} for
              dict_left, dict_entities, dict_right in
              zip(left, entities, right)]
```

The problem was indexing in the right words, after the last entity, there was no word. It was complaining of trying to reach the last object. I added the index size controller to fix the problem.

I also had to separate the blocks of `if`'s for JSON tags to get more precise results for each tag. Then simply merge them by using `zip()`